# How to add custom populated data to ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, internationalization, ngx-bootstrap

I have a datepicker in my application which should have data(whole calendar date saved in the database not the single saved data). I found no solution on ngx-bootstrap official website. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I didn't try. I have saved data in DB and got in the angular component. i am stuck in that.